# C++ template meta progr. conditional memory allocation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to implement a simple Linear-Algebra library (for learning purposes).

Problem => I would like the `Matrix` template class to either declare a fixed-size array at compile time, or use dynamic memory allocation if the number of `Rows` and `Columns` are not yet known.

How can i effectively / correctly do that? (i already have a simple / naive idea):

```
const long Dynamic = -1;

template<typename T, long Rows, long Cols>
class Matrix {
    private:
        enum {
            kIsDynamicStorage = Rows == Dynamic || Cols == Dynamic
        };

        //?? conditional<is_dynamic_storage, vector<vector<T>>, T[Rows][Cols]> storage;
        // Use for fixed-size
        array<array<T, kIsDynamicStorage ? 0: Cols>, kIsDynamicStorage ? 0: Rows> storage;
        // Use for dynamic size
        vector<vector<T>> dynamic_storage;

    public:
        enum {
            kRowsAtCompileTime = Rows,
            kColsAtCompileTime = Cols
        };


        Matrix();
        // Use for dynamic size
        Matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols);
};
```

Is there a correct / better way to do this?

Comment: Why not make two classes `DynamicMatrix` and `StaticMatrix` and let them both inherit from `Matrix`?

Comment: Why not make "Dynamic" a template parameter, and specialize Matrix on that? Or just make two seperate classes. Either way, the methods are likely to have different implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `std::conditional` ?

```
  static constexpr bool isDS { (Rows == Dynamic) || (Cols == Dynamic) };

  typename std::conditional<isDS,
     std::vector<std::vector<T>>,
     std::array<std::array<T, Cols>, Rows>>::type  storage;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I initialy considered this approach, but was worried, that, if the project get bigger, using a template-meta-programming approach would be much more complicated and would lead to less readable code than just creating a `DynamicMatrix` and a `StaticMatrix` child class. Are there any best practices for this sort of problem?

Comment: @LeoG. - I don't know if there are best practices but I suspect that heavily depends on what and how do you, exactly, intend to develop in your class. So it seems to me that only you are able to respond to this question.